# How can a clean/smudge filter determine its data stream's file name?

Tags: git, git-filter

In contrast to [githooks](/questions/tagged/githooks), `clean` and `smudge` are mere filters which are intended to directly process the file contents without being aware of any `git` functionality (since one may want to use native tools as `cat` or even `gzip`). But are there any environment variables or other means (other than scanning the repo for the file just getting fed with) to obtain the processed file's path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clean and smudge filters are invoked once per file, with arguments.  A `%f` in an argument is expanded to the file path, according to [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html#_tt_filter_tt) (scan down a bit inside the `filter` section).

Note that the smudge filter is not invoked (or re-invoked) in some cases you might expect.  This includes `git show` (or so I am told; I have not tested this).

Comment: Thanks, my eyes must have jumped over that... `git show`'s behaviour does make sense, it is equivalent to `git cat-file -p` for blob I guess, and it shows the content of a file as git sees it (in the "clean" state). That also makes sense in light of the paragraph "One use of the content filtering is to massage the content into a shape that is more convenient for the platform, filesystem, and the user to use. For this mode of operation, the key phrase here is "more convenient" and not "turning something unusable into usable"."

Comment: Two more notes: The "merge" section mentions setting `merge.renormalize` to run contents through filters during merge.  I have not experimented with this.  And, someone (VonC?) mentioned somewhere, or I read in some documentation, that when git succeeds with a simple two-way merge (using `read-tree -m`) it sometimes does not invoke the filters either.

Comment: Doesn't the merge act on the committed, clean-filtered contents by _default_? That's actually what I'd expect and want, and the smudge-filter should only be applied before checking out the merge result.

Comment: https://schacon.github.io/git/gitattributes.html#_merging_branches_with_differing_checkin_checkout_attributes suggests this setting is optional in order to avoid filter-related merge conflicts that can be fixed by unfiltering

Comment: That's the same text as in the documentation I linked.  Again, I have not experimented with this.  Assuming you're right that the merge works on "internal format", the intent would be to handle the case of "oh, dammit, $base version or $other version has CR+LF when all the new cleaned up ones have plain LF endings", for instance.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I understand it as well. So it should work fine with a fresh repo, which is the case for me. Thanks for the additional note